# Функция удаления экранирования символов типа \n \t

Tags: php, строки, функции

Есть строка, содержащая последовательности типа `\n, \t, \', \\`.
Есть ли в php встроенная функция для удаления таких последовательностей, и превращения их в реальные символы (перенос строки, табуляция, ...). Функция `stripslashes` не катит, т.к. она только слеши удаляет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ на вопрос - [stripcslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripcslashes.php)